# How can I add Gallery with my own ColorPalette to ContextMenuPly?

Tags: excel, xml, vba

ContextMenuPly ··· Label Color > Theme Color
How to put my own colors here or create Gallery for my colors, please share some XML or VBA? Colors I want to add for example:

```
ActiveSheet.Tab.Color = RGB(251, 206, 177) 'Apricot
ActiveSheet.Tab.Color = RGB(181, 184, 177) 'Agate Grey
ActiveSheet.Tab.Color = RGB(120, 219, 226) 'Aquamarine Crayola
ActiveSheet.Tab.Color = RGB(227, 38, 54) 'Alizarin Red
```

[image]

I already have Gallery for Cell "Context Menu". I'm using XML + VBA.
VBA code:

```
Sub TabColor_1()
ActiveSheet.Tab.Color = RGB(251, 206, 177) 'Apricot
End Sub

Sub TabColor_2()
ActiveSheet.Tab.Color = RGB(181, 184, 177) 'Agate Grey
End Sub

Sub TabColor_3()
ActiveSheet.Tab.Color = RGB(120, 219, 226) 'Aquamarine Crayola
End Sub

Sub TabColor_4()
ActiveSheet.Tab.Color = RGB(227, 38, 54) 'Alizarin Red
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[SOLVED]**

...find some tricks.

NOTE:

- You can add only 50 colors!
- You need 7-zip.
- Not working for Excel.
- File `theme1.xml` is also applicable in all Office programs.

---

### For Custom Colors:

[Introduction to XML in PowerPoint](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gAnGA2wYs4w&t=2s)
[Create Custom Colors in XML - PowerPoint Template creation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UBep9z_20M8&t=4s)

1. Open .pptx; docx files with 7-zip.
2. Changes you make in the file - `\ppt\theme\theme1.xml` ¦ `\word\theme\theme1.xml`...
3. After the line `<a:extraClrSchemeLst/>` add:

```xml
<a:custClrLst>
    <a:custClr name="Muslim green"><a:srgbClr val="009900"/></a:custClr>
    <a:custClr name="Mouse-grey"><a:srgbClr val="646B63"/></a:custClr>
    <a:custClr name="Mint cream"><a:srgbClr val="F5FFFA"/></a:custClr>
    <a:custClr name="Narcissus yellow"><a:srgbClr val="DC9D00"/></a:custClr>
    <a:custClr name="Rich brown"><a:srgbClr val="753313"/></a:custClr>
</a:custClrLst>
```

---

### For Recent Colors:

[Recent Colors Palette in PowerPoint - XML](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3PpNQS7Sc3g)

1. Open .pptx file with 7-zip (i've tested only in PowerPoint).
2. Changes do in file - `\ppt\presProps.xml`.
3. After lines “xmlns :a :r :p” should be so:

```xml
<p:clrMru>
    <a:srgbClr val="AB274F"/>
    <a:srgbClr val="6E5160"/>
    <a:srgbClr val="003153"/>
</p:clrMru>
```

4. To remove all Recent Colors just put this `<p:clrMru/>`.

---

*Add-ins which can help to create Color Palette*:

- [YOUtool](http://youpresent.co.uk/office-add-ins/youtools-for-powerpoint/) (pay)   [Color Swatch](http://skp.mvps.org/swatch.htm) (free)

Comment: Here's a process you can use to get this working in Excel:
1. Select this as the theme within Excel.
2. Create a chart with some dummy data.
3. Select the chart series and change the fill/line colour to one of the custom colours that appears in the drop down. Ensure the colour of the line/interior changes.
4. From now on, the custom colours section will appear in the fill/font colour dropdown -- even if you then delete the chart.

Comment: @Mrfence - maybe you can show me screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom option to the right-click menu named "My Custom Colors" that will change the color of your worksheet labels by placing the code below in the module for ThisWorksheet.  Inside this code, you call the TabColor subs that are in your regular modules.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()


Dim MyMenu As Object


Set MyMenu = Application.ShortcutMenus(xlWorksheetCell) _
    .MenuItems.AddMenu("My Custom Colors", 1)


With MyMenu.MenuItems


    .Add "Apricot", "TabColor_1", , 1, , ""

    .Add "Agate Grey", "TabColor_2", , 2, , ""

End With


Set MyMenu = Nothing

End Sub


Sub TabColor_1()

ActiveSheet.Tab.Color = RGB(251, 206, 177) 'Apricot


End Sub

Sub TabColor_2()

ActiveSheet.Tab.Color = RGB(181, 184, 177) 'Agate Grey

End Sub
```

[image]

**REVISION #1**

You can add the galleries for the cell shading and the font color to the context menu using these xmls... There are a couple of variants below based on what you want.

```
<gallery idMso="CellFillColorPicker"/>
<gallery idMso="FontColorPicker"/> 


<!-- DropDownColorPickers -->
<Command Name="cmdDropDownColorPickerGroup"
         Symbol="cmdDropDownColorPickerGroup"
         Comment="DropDownColorPicker Group"
         Id="55000"/>
<Command Name="cmdDropDownColorPickerThemeColors"
         Symbol="cmdDropDownColorPickerThemeColors"
         Comment="DropDownColorPicker ThemeColors"
         Id="55010"
         LabelTitle="ThemeColors"
         LabelDescription="ThemeColors\ndescription."/>
<Command Name="cmdDropDownColorPickerStandardColors"
         Symbol="cmdDropDownColorPickerStandardColors"
         Comment="DropDownColorPicker StandardColors"
         Id="55011"
         LabelTitle="StandardColors"/>
<Command Name="cmdDropDownColorPickerHighlightColors"
         Symbol="cmdDropDownColorPickerHighlightColors"
         Comment="DropDownColorPicker HighlightColors"
         Id="55012"
         LabelTitle="HighlightColors"/>


<Group CommandName=&quot;cmdDropDownColorPickerGroup&quot;
           SizeDefinition=&quot;ThreeButtons&quot;>
      <DropDownColorPicker
        CommandName=&quot;cmdDropDownColorPickerThemeColors&quot;
        ColorTemplate=&quot;ThemeColors&quot;/>
      <DropDownColorPicker
        CommandName=&quot;cmdDropDownColorPickerStandardColors&quot;
        ColorTemplate=&quot;StandardColors&quot;/>
      <DropDownColorPicker
        CommandName=&quot;cmdDropDownColorPickerHighlightColors&quot;
        ColorTemplate=&quot;HighlightColors&quot;
        StandardColorGridRows=&quot;1&quot;/>
    </Group>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/windowsribbon/windowsribbon-controls-dropdowncolorpicker

Comment: ··· Omg i know how to add to «Cell» `RightClickMenu`. Question is... How to add “Color Palette” to «Ply» `RightClickMenu (Context Menu)`.

Comment: Sorry, I see what you mean now.  You can add the galleries for the cell shading and the font color to the context menu using these xmls (I also edited the answer)...  <gallery idMso="CellFillColorPicker"/>
<gallery idMso="FontColorPicker"/>

Comment: ··· I looked at the documentation but I didn't understand!? Where do you put all this? Do I need to use «Visual Studio» + VSTO? Do you know any video lessons?